# Update or Edit aria lables in botframework (Accessibility)

Tags: reactjs, botframework

I have a requirement to add an aria-label or update/edit aria-label value I am new to bot framework webchat code please let me know how to add/update and i am using react js

Need a flexible way to add aria-label or edit using react js or any shortcut way to add it in bot framework webchat

[update aria lablee](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuWUo.png)

[adding aria-lable to button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0SYb.png)

Comment: Which label are you trying to change, and what do you want to change it to? Off the bat, my suggestion would be to rewrite the components you want to change the label for in a fork of Web Chat.

Comment: Thanks for the repli. I want to add aria lable to send button tag and to time stamp

Comment: Web Chat 4.5.2 has an update where timestamps are now spoken by the AT as absolute time. Please check out that update and see if it fulfills your needs. As far as I know, the Send button passes accessibility requirements, but if you require changes to be made, you will need to rewrite the send button component. This would require implementing your own send box as well. If you believe there are accessibility ERRORS on Web Chat, please feel free to report them on the Web Chat repo. :)